# Jsoup best method to get an Element from a string

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I obtain a Jsoup Element from a String?
For example if I have a String

```
String myDiv = "<div>Hello jsoup world</div>";
```

that I want to convert in an Element.
Currently I convert the String in a Document with the Jsoup.parse(..) method and then I get the body of that document as Element. Is there a direct method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the *XML-Parser* instead the HTML one:

```
final String html = "<div>Hello jsoup world</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
Element tag = doc;
```

Or shorter:

```
Element tag = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: Just if anybody is curious, how to parse multiple elements:
`Elements elems = Jsoup.parse("<b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b>", "", Parser.xmlParser()).select("b");`

Comment: beware for tags which do not have closing tag, like `img`. For these closing tag will be added.

Answer (score 1):

As a note to the accepted answer, for my use case, using the xmlParser messed up some instances of '>' literals (inline style tag), changing them into HTML string entities.

It seems that using Parser.htmlParser() may be a better option in some cases, and the result can cast to Element.

```
Element element = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.htmlParser());
```